# How uninstall Win 10 update? (it broke my miracast)

Tags: windows-10, miracast

How do I get the below removed? (Specifically, the updates highlighted in yellow)

One of these broke my miracast. (Dell XPS 13 laptop)

[image]

My next step on this process is here: [How to troubleshoot miracast on windows 10 laptop?](https://superuser.com/q/1275906/15466)

Comment: One of them is an update to Flash which is not the cause of Miracast not working.  You can uninstall KB4051613 like any other update.  Removing it will of course leave you vulnerable to any vulnerabilities it patches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to uninstall updates:

1. Control Panel:
   Open the control panel and select Programs and Features. On the left hand side, click "View Installed Updates". Select the update you would like to uninstall and click uninstall.
2. Command Prompt:
   Open the command prompt and issue this command (replacing "number here" with the KB number of the update:

   ```
   wusa /uninstall /kb:"number here"
   ```