# How does VPN client affect Miracast?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, miracast

I am on a Dell laptop, that came stock w Win 10, and my miracast is broken. (It worked since the beginning, then broke one day.)

I initially thought (per [How to troubleshoot miracast on windows 10 laptop?](https://superuser.com/q/1275906/15466) ) that a windows update caused the issue. I now think the installation of the Sonicwall VPN Netextender client caused the problem. (And, fwiw, I have both Sonicwall Netextender AND Cisco Anyconnect vpn clients, I use them both. I had anyconnect for some months with no miracast problem, but when I put on Netextender....)

There are documented conflicts between Miracast and some vpn clients ( http://digitalmediaphile.com/index.php/2015/04/24/trouble-shooting-miracast/ and other threads)

But I have tried uninstalling Netextender and rebooting, and miracast did not come back to life (and I need Netextender!).

How do I:

a) Get logging data out of miracast on the laptop to help diag the issue?

or

b) "Walk" the networking stack to (hopefully) identify what is messing w Miracast

or

c) ___ ?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution to the problem here: https://superuser.com/a/1328168/15466

Comment: Hey Sam, can you post a diagram of your setup topology, with the make and model numbers of the devices your using & how they are connected. It sounds like a firewall issue is blocking it. Possible it's blocked by one of the VPN clients as it may be seen as a "split tunnel"

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Sorry, I don't follow. This is just a laptop, trying to use miracast to a Microsoft wireless display adapter: https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-gb/products/adapters/microsoft-wireless-display-adapter/cg4-00003  There is no architecture.