# Miracast no longer working on Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, drivers, miracast

I have a Dell Inspiron 17 5748 running Windows 10 1709 (Fall Creators Update). A good year ago I was able to wirelessly duplicate my laptop's screen to a Samsung UE40J6200 TV. I remember having to install an Intel wireless card and the need to install a piece of software called Intel WiDi to make it work.

I didn't use the functionality for a while and have reinstalled Windows 10 on that laptop since. I looked for the WiDi drivers and found that Intel has discontinued the product saying that Windows now has good Miracast support that can be used instead. The additional bonus would be that an Intel wireless card is no longer required.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to use it with this laptop since then. Whenever I put my TV in the "screen mirroring" mode, the laptop is able to see the TV when choosing the function to connect to a wireless display. The laptop seems to be able to connect and usually the TV will show the laptop's display for about 5 seconds before the image either freezes or the connection is dropped.

What I have tried so far:

- Updated wireless card drivers to latest version
- Updated graphics card drivers to the latest version on the Dell website
- Updated graphics card drivers to the latest version from Intel (using a manual installation option because apparently Dell blocks the installation of the generic Intel drivers now)
- Tried a different Windows 10 machine (a Cherrytrail tablet with a Realtek wireless card. This works fine although the tablet doesn't have the latest Windows updates)
- Tried a Windows 10 Mobile device. This works fine.
- Verified that the driver and hardware supports a wireless display using dxdiag (using these instructions: [How to check if your PC supports Miracast](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-check-if-your-pc-supports-miracast-wireless-streaming/)
- Verified that the system supports a wireless display using an alternate method (netsh wlan sho d command in a command prompt)
- Connected laptop and TV to my 2.4GHz wireless network instead of having the laptop on the 5GHz network and the TV connected with a wire (this shouldn't matter as Miracast uses WiFi Direct)

I'm now at my wits end as to what I can try next. Google tells me many people complain about Miracast being broken after certain Windows 10 updates but there is never a definite solution available.

The relevant hardware:

- Core i5 5200U with Intel HD Graphics 5500
- Intel AC7265 wireless card
- Samsung UE40J6200 TV
- Wireless network running on my provider's router (5GHz 802.11AC with a 40MHz wide channel on free channels, 2.4GHz 802.11N with a 20MHz channel and having interference from neighbor's access points)

**Update on April 5 2019:** Still no luck in getting this to work, even with the latest Windows 10 updates. The screen stays black. Using Miracast with a Nokia 6 phone running Android 9 works flawlessly.

Comment: Try : (1) Turn Firewall Defender off, and If this works then create a firewall rule. (2) Right-click the desktop / Display settings / Scroll to Projecting to this PC, and change "Setting: Windows PC's and Phones can project: Available everywhere on secure networks" to "Available everywhere".

Comment: @harrymc I have tried your suggestion but the problem seems to have worsened in the meanwhile. The computer no longer even finds the TV when searching for wireless displays. Turning off the firewall or changing the projection settings did not help.

Comment: If you are experiencing a degradation, this becomes another problem. If you can, try to see what happens when booting in Safe mode with Networking (if it applies).  Check the system with [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Do several deep antivirus scans.

Comment: @harrymc Projecting to a wireless display doesn't work in safe mode as it relies on the graphics card's driver support. I have checked the system although I don't expect a relation between malware and this problem. Miracast also works only intermittently on my Windows 10 tablet where it varies between working well and not seeing the TV at all.

Comment: What is your graphics card ?

Comment: @harrymc The system has no discrete graphics card. I'm using the CPU's Intel HD Graphics 5500.

Comment: Did you install the [Intel Graphics Driver for Windows version 15.40](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27267/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-)?

Comment: Yes I did. First I tried the latest version that Dell offers. When that didn't work I updated the driver to that version.

Comment: Please add to your post the output of the command `Netsh wlan sho D`. I hope that the last line says "Wireless Display Supported: Yes".

Comment: I don't have the device with me right now but I did run that command and the output said that it was supported and that the graphics card and wifi card also supported it. I ran it again after the device was unable to see the TV and it still says the same.

Comment: Have you updated the firmware of the TV? The latest is apparently version 1510.4 from 2017.09.26. You may also try to find in Device Manager something with Miracast and report on the driver. Check also if you have the latest BIOS.

Comment: Good point about the TV firmware. The TV's internet access is deliberately blocked to avoid Samsung sending me ads. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Try Windows 10 1607. 1709 might have broken compatibility with Dell as in Razer laptop.

Comment: Any news if updating the TV firmware has helped?

Comment: Not yet. It's been a busy weekend!

Comment: 2017-11 Update is alleged to break Miracast [\[1\]](https://superuser.com/questions/1275745), on an Intel 6th generation PC [\[2\]](https://superuser.com/questions/1275906).

Comment: Not having any return, I have summarized my advice in an answer.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I changed my Samsung smart tv wifi connection from 5Ghz to 2.4Ghz and my thinkpad connected to it flawlessly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be drivers or BIOS. You may find these at :

- The firmware of the TV at the Samsung site,
  where the latest is apparently
  [version 1510.4](http://www.samsung.com/fr/support/model/UE40J6200AWXZF)
  from 2017.09.26. The TV can also update itself if connected to the Internet.
- The latest Dell drivers and BIOS for your motherboard at the page of
  [Support for Inspiron 5748 - Drivers & downloads​](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-17-5748-laptop/drivers?lwp=rt)
- The latest
  [Intel drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/85212/Intel-Core-i5-5200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2-70-GHz-).
- You may also verify in Device Manager the make of the driver of the
  Miracast device and search for an update.

If all your drivers and firmware are up to date but the problem persists,
the problem is then with Windows 10 version 1709,
and you will have to wait for Microsoft to fix it.
I don't recommend downgrading to an earlier version of Windows,
as some have advocated, because of security concerns,
and also because Windows will update itself automatically back to version
1709.

Comment: Have tried everything including the TV firmware update which I did last night. I was up half the night trying different settings but alas... Appreciate your efforts and going to select this answer as correct. It indeed seems to be a Windows 10 issue and I agree not to downgrade for Miracast support.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did to get miracast to work.
go to all settings-system-shared experience.
turn on nearby sharing so your computer can find the tv.
turn off nearby sharing then use connect to connect to the tv.

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was resolved by manually setting the interface metric for IPv4 and IPv6 to high numbers (100 and 99) for the Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter and the Palo Alto Networks Global Protect (PANGP VPN) connection.  I have Windows 10 build 1803, updated display drivers, wi-fi drivers, BIOS, docking station firmware, etc... (I tried many many things before resolving this).

Windows Settings->Network & Internet->Status->Change adpater options

For me, the Miracast display connection was called "Local Area Connection 2", and the PANGP connection was called "Ethernet 2".  Right click on the one that represents your Miracast connection, select Properties, highlight Internet Protocal Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and select properties, click on Advanced, unselect Automatic Metric and type 100 in the Interface Metric box.  Click Ok twice, then do the same thing for Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6).  I did the same for PANGP, but used the number 99 - for no real good reason, just saying what worked - other numbers probably will work...

Review the ifIndex and InterfaceMetric for all connections by opening a Administrator Powershell terminal (Windows key-X then select "Windows Powershell (Admin)").  Type "Get-NetIPInterface".

Comment: Tried this but it did not resolve the issue for me.